# Sorting a list of strings with a specific method

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

let's say i have a list of strings like this

```
L = ['5', '3', '4', '1', '2', '2 3 5', '2 4 8', '5 22 1 37', '5 22 1 22', '5 22 1 23', ....]
```

How can i sort this list so that i would have something like this:

```
L = ['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '2 3 5', '2 4 8', '5 22 1 22', ' 5 22 1 23', '5 22 1 37', ...]
```

basically i need to order the list based on the first different number between 2 strings

Comment: Does the length of the string really matter? Where would `'4 2'` appear in your result, before or after `'5'`?

Comment: yes the lenght matters, so '4 2' would be after 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sort using a tuple:

```
L = ['5', '3', '4', '1', '2', '2 3 5', '2 4 8', '5 22 1 37', '5 22 1 22', '5 22 1 23']

result = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (len(x.split()),) + tuple(map(int, x.split())))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '2 3 5', '2 4 8', '5 22 1 22', '5 22 1 23', '5 22 1 37']
```

The idea is to use as key a tuple where the first element is the amount of numbers in the string and the rest is the tuple of numbers. For example for `'2 3 5'` the key is `(3, 2, 3, 5)`

As suggested by @PM2Ring you could use a `def` function instead of a `lambda`:

```
def key(x):
    numbers = tuple(map(int, x.split()))
    return (len(numbers),) + numbers
```

Comment: Maybe use a `def` function instead of a `lambda` for the key function so you don't have to call `x.split` twice on each item.

Comment: Once Python 3.8 comes out, you could write `lambda x: (len(y:=x.split()),) + tuple(map(int, y)))`. (Personally, I'd still pre-define the function, but there appear to be people who like the syntax that PEP-572 settled on.)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach than @Daniel's one.

```
idx = sorted(range(len(L)), key=lambda i: int(''.join(L[i].split())))
L = [L[i] for i in idx]
```

**output**

```
['1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '2 3 5',
 '2 4 8',
 '5 22 1 22',
 '5 22 1 23',
 '5 22 1 37']
```